# How to get columns from a query in python?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have that query in a `python` program:

And i should create a multidimensional array (if it possible) or four arrays from this query for every column from the query.

Can you suggest an elegant way to solve it?

```
conn = #connection to the server
cursor=conn.cursor()
query = (" select id, name, phone, city from guest")

cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall
for i in results:
     print i
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Lets see what you have in code, so we can help you get the result.

Comment: A query of what, exactly?

Comment: looks like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is what you need

Comment: when you do `results = cursor.fetchall()`, `result` is already a list of tuples with the data from the query (or a multidimentional array ), if you want a specific column, ask for it in the query, or extract it from result

Comment: you can check the examples in the documentation of [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html)

Answer (score -1):

Not elegant but it may assist to unravel the mysterious Python Connector Cursor Class and transfers the list of tuples (see Copperfield comment) with the data from the query, into a list (phoneList) of dictionaries (entries) with details of each entry in the database, that might be easier to work with in your python script:

```
# ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html
import mysql.connector

db = 'test'
table = 'phonebook'
phoneList = []

drop_table   = ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {};").format(table)
# By default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.
# To let the AUTO_INCREMENT sequence start with another value, use the following SQL statement:
# ALTER TABLE phonebook AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
create_table = ("CREATE TABLE {} ("
            "id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            "name varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
            "phone varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
            "city  varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
            "PRIMARY KEY (id))"
            " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;").format(table)

Names = {'Bill':{'phone':'55123123','city':'Melbourne'},
     'Mary':{'phone':'77111123','city':'Sydney'},
     'Sue':{'phone':'55888123','city':'Melbourne'},
     'Harry':{'phone':'77777123','city':'Sydney'},
     'Fred':{'phone':'88123444','city':'Yongala'},
     'Peter':{'phone':'55999123','city':'Melbourne'}}


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='mysqluser', password='xxxx',host='127.0.0.1',database=db)
cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)  # key to using **row format
cursor.execute(drop_table)
cursor.execute(create_table)
# populate db
for name,detail in dict.items(Names):
    sql = ("INSERT INTO {} (name,phone,city) VALUES ('{}','{}','{}')".format(table,name,detail['phone'],detail['city']))
    cursor.execute(sql)

sql = ("SELECT id,name,phone,city FROM {}".format(table))
cursor.execute(sql)

for row in cursor:
    print("{id} {name} {phone} {city}".format(**row))
    phoneList.append(row)

print phoneList[0]['name'],phoneList[0]['city']
print phoneList[3]['name'],phoneList[3]['phone']


for entries in phoneList: # list of dictionaries
    print entries['name'],entries

for entries in phoneList:
    for k,v in dict.items(entries):
        print k,v
    print "\n"

cnx.close()
```

Comment: `sql = ("INSERT INTO phonebook (name,phone,city) VALUES ('"+name+"','"+detail['phone']+"','"+detail['city']+"')".format(table))` is an accident waiting to happen, [mom of little Bobby Tables would say](https://xkcd.com/327/). Never concatenate or format values to SQL queries. [Always use placeholders](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).

Comment: Can't argue with Mom -  sql = ("INSERT INTO {} (name,phone,city) VALUES ('{}','{}','{}')".format(table,name,detail['phone'],detail['city']))
Howzat?

Comment: "Or format". Please read on [SQL injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and mitigation, especially parameterized queries. The trick is to use placeholders in the query that the *DB-API driver* fills in from passed values.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I see if this was used to accept user inputs from a webpage it could potentially destroy your database, so a practice to avoid.  My example avoids injection as it populates the database without user inputs just to provide data as a tool to demonstrate the creation of a multidimensional array from the cursor class for @Daniel.  [W3schools SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) another good link on this topic.

Comment: That and also if a name like "O'Malley" happened to be in the initial data. Unfortunately there's no way to pass identifiers as parameters (table names and such), so in your example that is unavoidable, but usually identifiers are not user controlled. MySQL connector uses percent placeholders, so the proper way would be `sql = "INSERT INTO {} (name,phone,city) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)".format(table)` and then `cursor.execute(sql, (name,detail['phone'],detail['city']))`. Note that those are *not* Python's old style string formatting placeholders, though similar, so `sql % (...)` is *not* used.

Comment: On MySQL connector and inserting initial data, there's also [`executemany()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html): instead of calling execute in a loop, you could `cursor.executemany(sql, [(name,detail['phone'],detail['city']) for name, detail in Names.items()])`. That is where parameterized queries shine, and MySQL connector actually optimizes executemany on INSERTs: it sends just 1 query to the DB with multiple VALUES.